# PHP MYsql Query Chinese Character

Tags: php, mysql

PHP MYsql Query Chinese Character

I did the following

My database was set to UTF-8

I also did the code

```
SET NAMES 'UTF8';
SET CHARACTER SET 'UTF8';
```

My sql was able draw the data out from my table using php mysql query select all rows, then display in a HTML page, the Chinese character nicely as Chinese words.

But when I try to do a select statement by i, below is the result

```
select * from account;

|       1 | æ�Žé€µ               |
|       2 | å®‹æ±Ÿ               |
```

The text will appear in this weird format above, so I did the following to draw the Individual record

```
SELECT role_id,UserId FROM accounts where UserName='宋宋';
```

However it did not get the result, although the Chinese character match.

The weird thing is if I select all rows, and display them out in a table, it looks perfectly like the chinese word that was key in.

But when I type the word in mysql itself or trying use mysql select statement by the chinese character, the statement yield 0 row which suppose to be 1 row.

TL:DR

How do I do a **sql select statement where the input is in Chinese character**, M
y record in sql is not in the chinese format (although it display in Chinese word if i echo it weird encoding into a html table)

**Thanks**

Comment: The table is also in utf-8?

Comment: Take care to explicitly set your client to unicode. Without it has to _guess_ the correct encoding, which obviously may fail give too little data.

Comment: @arkascha how do I get the unicode setting of my database / table

Comment: my collation is latin1_swedish_ci

Comment: The collation is not of interest currently. Check your database and table setup, either by using a management system like the mysql workbench or phpmyadmin. Or you can query these setting by means of sql, take a look at the documentation for that, it is pretty precise.